# Force jQuery submenu navigation to disappear on mouseout

Tags: jquery, menu, treeview, hover, mouseout

I'm working on building a website for a client, which was designed by my supervisor. Early on, it was decided that our navigation would be based on the jQuery TreeView Menu (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm).

Initially, my supervisors liked the look and functionality of the TreeView navigation. But after I installed and built the navigation, they changed their minds. Now they just want the look of the branches, but with the basic functionality of a drop down menu.

I'm no jQuery expert, so it's incredibly difficult for me to edit the code. But I've gotten it to do what I want--with one exception. I'd like the sub menus to disappear on mouseout, but they remain there until you move the mouse to another element. Is there a way to do this with the framework I've got, or should I rebuild from scratch and make it all CSS-based?

Another option would be to keep the hover states of each main navigation link active until you move to another link. At this point, the background image, which serves as the connecting branch disappears on mouseout, while the submenus do not.

I basically just want the background image of the main menu items to appear/disappear when the submenu boxes do.

The test site can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/7novfmc

Here's my CSS:

```
#navigation a {
color:#666;
text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation a:hover {
color:#C93;
text-decoration:none;
}
.navlink a:hover {
color:#C93;
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url(../images/treeview-horizontal-line.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
padding-right:17px;
}
.treeview, .treeview ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}
.treeview ul {
background-color: #FFF;
margin-top: 4px;
}
.treeview .hitarea {
/*background: url(../images/treeview-default.gif) -64px -25px no-repeat;*/
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
margin-left: -16px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}
/* fix for IE6 */
* html .hitarea {
display: inline;
float:none;
}
.treeview li {
margin: 0;
padding: 12px 0pt 16px 16px;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-size: .75em;
}
.treeview a.selected {
background-color: #eee;
}
#treecontrol {
margin: 1em 0;
display: none;
}
.treeview .hover {
color: #C93;
cursor: pointer;
}
.treeview li ul li {
background: url(../images/treeview-orange-line1.png) 0 10px no-repeat;
font-size: 1em;
margin-top:-24px;
}
.treeview li.collapsable, .treeview li.expandable {
background-position: 0 -176px;
}
.treeview .expandable-hitarea {
background-position: -80px -3px;
}
.treeview li.last {
background-position: 0 -1766px
}
.treeview li.lastCollapsable, .treeview li.lastExpandable {
}
.treeview li.lastCollapsable {
background-position: 0 -111px
}
.treeview li.lastExpandable {
background-position: -32px -67px
}
.treeview div.lastCollapsable-hitarea, .treeview div.lastExpandable-hitarea {
background-position: 0;
}
.treeview-famfamfam li {
background-image: url(../images/treeview-famfamfam-line.gif);
}
.treeview-famfamfam .hitarea, .treeview-famfamfam li.lastCollapsable, .treeview-famfamfam li.lastExpandable {
background-image: url(../images/treeview-famfamfam.gif);
}
.filetree li {
padding: 3px 0 2px 16px;
}
.filetree span.folder, .filetree span.file {
padding: 1px 0 1px 16px;
display: block;
}
.filetree span.folder {
background: url(../images/folder.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.filetree li.expandable span.folder {
background: url(../images/folder-closed.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.filetree span.file {
background: url(../images/file.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Here's my HTML (with some inline CSS):

```
            <div id="HEADER_NAVIGATION">
            <div id="MAIN_NAVIGATION">
              <ul id="navigation">
                <li style="margin-left:60px;"><span class="navlink"><a href="about.html">About</a></span>
                    <ul style="margin-left:40px;margin-top:-32px;position:fixed;">
                        <li>Our Approach</li>
                        <li>Experience</li>
                        <li>Global Reach</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li style="margin-left:75px;"><a href="principals.html">Principals</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left:90px;"><span class="navlink"><a href="offerings.html">Offerings</a></span>
                    <ul style="margin-left:60px;margin-top:-34px;position:fixed;">
                        <li>Performance Improvement</li>
                        <li>Organizational Transformation</li>
                        <li>Solutions Architecture</li>
                        <li>Risk Management</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li style="margin-left:75px;"><span><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></span>
                    <ul style="margin-left:70px;margin-top:-3px;position:fixed;">
                        <!--<li>Case Studies</li>-->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li style="margin-left:60px;"><span class="navlink"><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></span>
                    <ul style="margin-left:65px;margin-top:-13px;position:fixed;">
                        <li>Strategic Alliances</li>
                        <li>Publications</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="MAIN_HEADER_IMAGE"></div>
        </div>
```

And here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// first example
$("#navigation").treeview({
    collapsed: true,
    unique: true,
    persist: "location"
});
});
```

---

```
;(function($) {

$.extend($.fn, {
    swapClass: function(c1, c2) {
        var c1Elements = this.filter('.' + c1);
        this.filter('.' + c2).removeClass(c2).addClass(c1);
        c1Elements.removeClass(c1).addClass(c2);
        return this;
    },
    replaceClass: function(c1, c2) {
        return this.filter('.' + c1).removeClass(c1).addClass(c2).end();
    },
    hoverClass: function(className) {
        className = className || "hover";
        return this.hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass(className);
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass(className);
        });
    },
    heightToggle: function(animated, callback) {
        animated ?
            this.animate({ height: "toggle" }, animated, callback) :
            this.each(function(){
                jQuery(this)[ jQuery(this).is(":hidden") ? "show" : "show" ](); // default here is "show" : "hide"
                if(callback)
                    callback.apply(this, arguments);
            });
    },
    heightHide: function(animated, callback) {
        if (animated) {
            this.animate({ height: "hide" }, animated, callback);
        } else {
            this.hide();
            if (callback)
                this.each(callback);                
        }
    },
    prepareBranches: function(settings) {
        if (!settings.prerendered) {
            // mark last tree items
            this.filter(":last-child:not(ul)").addClass(CLASSES.last);
            // collapse whole tree, or only those marked as closed, anyway except those marked as open
            this.filter((settings.collapsed ? "" : "." + CLASSES.closed) + ":not(." + CLASSES.open + ")").find(">ul").hide();
        }
        // return all items with sublists
        return this.filter(":has(>ul)");
    },
    applyClasses: function(settings, toggler) {
        this.filter(":has(>ul):not(:has(>a))").find(">span").hover(function(event) {
            toggler.apply($(this).next());
        }).add( $("a", this) ).hoverClass();

        if (!settings.prerendered) {
            // handle closed ones first
            this.filter(":has(>ul:hidden)")
                    .addClass(CLASSES.expandable)
                    .replaceClass(CLASSES.last, CLASSES.lastExpandable);

            // handle open ones
            this.not(":has(>ul:hidden)")
                    .addClass(CLASSES.collapsable)
                    .replaceClass(CLASSES.last, CLASSES.lastCollapsable);

            // create hitarea
            this.prepend("<div class=\"" + CLASSES.hitarea + "\"/>").find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).each(function() {
                var classes = "";
                $.each($(this).parent().attr("class").split(" "), function() {
                    classes += this + "-hitarea ";
                });
                $(this).addClass( classes );
            });
        }

        // apply event to hitarea
        this.find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).mouseout( toggler );
    },
    treeview: function(settings) {

        settings = $.extend({
            cookieId: "treeview"
        }, settings);

        if (settings.add) {
            return this.trigger("add", [settings.add]);
        }

        if ( settings.toggle ) {
            var callback = settings.toggle;
            settings.toggle = function() {
                return callback.apply($(this).parent()[0], arguments);
            };
        }

        // factory for treecontroller
        function treeController(tree, control) {
            // factory for click handlers
            function handler(filter) {
                return function() {
                    // reuse toggle event handler, applying the elements to toggle
                    // start searching for all hitareas
                    toggler.apply( $("div." + CLASSES.hitarea, tree).filter(function() {
                        // for plain toggle, no filter is provided, otherwise we need to check the parent element
                        return filter ? $(this).parent("." + filter).length : true;
                    }) );
                    return false;
                };
            }
            // click on first element to collapse tree
            $("a:eq(0)", control).click( handler(CLASSES.collapsable) );
            // click on second to expand tree
            $("a:eq(1)", control).click( handler(CLASSES.expandable) );
            // click on third to toggle tree
            $("a:eq(2)", control).click( handler() ); 
        }

        // handle toggle event
        function toggler() {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                // swap classes for hitarea
                .find(">.hitarea")
                    .swapClass( CLASSES.collapsableHitarea, CLASSES.expandableHitarea )
                    .swapClass( CLASSES.lastCollapsableHitarea, CLASSES.lastExpandableHitarea )
                .end()
                // swap classes for parent li
                .swapClass( CLASSES.collapsable, CLASSES.expandable )
                .swapClass( CLASSES.lastCollapsable, CLASSES.lastExpandable )
                // find child lists
                .find( ">ul" )
                // toggle them
                .heightToggle( settings.animated, settings.toggle );
            if ( settings.unique ) {
                $(this).parent()
                    .siblings()
                    // swap classes for hitarea
                    .find(">.hitarea")
                        .replaceClass( CLASSES.collapsableHitarea, CLASSES.expandableHitarea )
                        .replaceClass( CLASSES.lastCollapsableHitarea, CLASSES.lastExpandableHitarea )
                    .end()
                    .replaceClass( CLASSES.collapsable, CLASSES.expandable )
                    .replaceClass( CLASSES.lastCollapsable, CLASSES.lastExpandable )
                    .find( ">ul" )
                    .heightHide( settings.animated, settings.toggle );
            }
        }

        function serialize() {
            function binary(arg) {
                return arg ? 1 : 0;
            }
            var data = [];
            branches.each(function(i, e) {
                data[i] = $(e).is(":has(>ul:visible)") ? 1 : 0;
            });
            $.cookie(settings.cookieId, data.join("") );
        }

        function deserialize() {
            var stored = $.cookie(settings.cookieId);
            if ( stored ) {
                var data = stored.split("");
                branches.each(function(i, e) {
                    $(e).find(">ul")[ parseInt(data[i]) ? "show" : "hide" ]();
                });
            }
        }

        // add treeview class to activate styles
        this.addClass("treeview");

        // prepare branches and find all tree items with child lists
        var branches = this.find("li").prepareBranches(settings);

        switch(settings.persist) {
        case "cookie":
            var toggleCallback = settings.toggle;
            settings.toggle = function() {
                serialize();
                if (toggleCallback) {
                    toggleCallback.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            };
            deserialize();
            break;
        case "location":
            var current = this.find("a").filter(function() { return this.href.toLowerCase() == location.href.toLowerCase(); });
            if ( current.length ) {
                current.addClass("selected").parents("ul, li").add( current.next() ).show();
            }
            break;
        }

        branches.applyClasses(settings, toggler);

        // if control option is set, create the treecontroller and show it
        if ( settings.control ) {
            treeController(this, settings.control);
            $(settings.control).show();
        }

        return this.bind("add", function(event, branches) {
            $(branches).prev()
                .removeClass(CLASSES.last)
                .removeClass(CLASSES.lastCollapsable)
                .removeClass(CLASSES.lastExpandable)
            .find(">.hitarea")
                .removeClass(CLASSES.lastCollapsableHitarea)
                .removeClass(CLASSES.lastExpandableHitarea);
            $(branches).find("li").andSelf().prepareBranches(settings).applyClasses(settings, toggler);
        });
    }
});

// classes used by the plugin
// need to be styled via external stylesheet, see first example
var CLASSES = $.fn.treeview.classes = {
    open: "open",
    closed: "closed",
    expandable: "expandable",
    expandableHitarea: "expandable-hitarea",
    lastExpandableHitarea: "lastExpandable-hitarea",
    collapsable: "collapsable",
    collapsableHitarea: "collapsable-hitarea",
    lastCollapsableHitarea: "lastCollapsable-hitarea",
    lastCollapsable: "lastCollapsable",
    lastExpandable: "lastExpandable",
    last: "last",
    hitarea: "hitarea"
};

// provide backwards compability
$.fn.Treeview = $.fn.treeview;

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that tree view plugin to do what you need.

Add to css

```
#navigation ul { display: none; }
#navigation li.hover ul { display: block; }
```

Change jquery to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navigation>li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
    );
});
```

Result http://jsfiddle.net/J3Khk/

You can also use plain css and ditch the javascript all together by using

```
#navigation ul { display: none; }
#navigation li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Result http://jsfiddle.net/cBf3c/

Edit: If you are using the plugin for just the tree view lines, you can do this with css as well. You can use a background image or if your clever enough you could probably do it with some absolutely positioned `<hr />`'s

Comment: Looks like it's working so far... Thanks so much! Rather than restyling the entire menu, I decided to rename the .treeview class selectors to #navigation. Seems to have worked. Now I just need to style the submenus to kill the branch image on the last item. Thanks again!